# Tree-ish Grid/hierarchical Grid in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, gridview, hierarchy

How could I work with hierarchical Grid in WPF like below one [image]

Is there any way to work with this type of grid through which we can show hierarchical data.
please discuss or give me any url from where I can download the source of sample code which help me to work with hierarchical grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across [Object List View](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) today, and it seems quite good. Doesn't seem to be a filtering and virtualization though.

Comment: The question asked for a WPF answer but the link is WinForms.

Answer (score 2):

I've already seen a similar question and the answer contained [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf_treelistview_control.aspx).

ListView is a little more different than DataGrid, because it doesn't have editing and sorting functionality. But the sorting isn't plain in your picture, so I think that there is no difference between two controls in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out: A xaml only treeview with columns

https://dlaa.me/blog/post/9898803

Answer (score 1):

The Xceed Datagrid for WPf has this functionality built in and the samples are extensive.

http://xceed.com/Grid_WPF_Intro.html

Have a look at the online demo.

Comment: i was looking for open source free component. xceed is not open source.

Answer (score 1):

The Xceed DataGrid offers this functionality and does offer the open source version. Its called Blueprint. You will receive the source code for the component.